# Quotients of automorphism groups of finite field extensions

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, automorphism-group, quotient-group

If $k\subset \ell\subset m$ are finite fields, then $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell /k)$ is the quotient $\mathrm{Aut}(m/k)/\mathrm{Aut}(m/\ell)$ (correct me if I'm wrong).

Does this work in a more general setting? As in, what if the restriction of $k, \ell, m$ to finite fields is removed?

Comment: It works when $m$ is Galois over $k$ and $\ell$ is Galois over $k$. This automatically happens in finite fields because all finite extensions are Galois in that setting. Otherwise, $\mathrm{Aut}(m/\ell)$ may fail to be normal in $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$.

Comment: In general given a tower $L/E/K$ with $L/K$ normal then $Aut(E/K) =N/Aut(L/E)$ where $N = \{ g\in Aut(L/K),g(E)=E\}$ $= \{ g\in Aut(L/K),g Aut(L/E)g^{-1}=Aut(L/E)\}$